# Calling a function with several arguments for every element in a collection

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've got a collection, for example, `std::vector<MyClass> elements;` and want to run a function for every element.

It's simple and transparent when the function has no arguments: `std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::mem_fun(&MyClass::MyFunction));`

The code starts looking ugly when the function has 1 argument and I need to use `std::bind_2nd`.

Is there a way (perhaps, using lambdas) to write a function call with several arguments?

Comment: IMHO using a simple range based `for()` loop instead of `for_each()` would look less ugly anyways.

Comment: Sure, I do this way, but looking for something more advanced.

Comment: Where should the additional arguments come from? Does `[arg1, arg2] (auto& elem) { elem.MyFunction(arg1, arg2); }` not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fun(&MyClass::MyFunction));
```

is equivalent to

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& obj) { obj.MyFunction(); });
```

Now that the invocation of `MyFunction` is done in your code, you can pass other parameters to it as needed:

```
std::string arg1 = "hello";
int arg2 = 123;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](auto& obj) { obj.MyFunction(arg1, arg2); });
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/H3Kafl)

Comment: Though the answer is correct, it works for c++14 compilers only. If you need to use c++11 compiler you need to replace  auto&  by  decltype(*v.begin())&

Answer (score 4):

`for_each` works but as you said it might look less readable. I prefer the range-based for syntax a lot:

```
for(auto& element : elements)
    element.foo( … );
```